# how to put a video in webapp page?

Tags: html, web-applications

I use :

```
<video src="./mov_bbb.ogg" x-webkit-airplay="allow" airplay="allow" controls="controls">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img src="../img/video.jpg" alt="play"></a>
</video>
```

to play video in webapp page,it works well on PC,but but not on Phone,why?

Comment: I would assume because Ogg video is not supported on your phone's OS, but since you haven't told us what OS your phone is I can't say for sure.

Comment: as u say, i tried MP4, and now it works well. Thank you!